# How does the local zenith angle evolve as a function of atmospheric vertical depth?

Tags: particle-physics, atmospheric-science, geometry, cosmic-rays

From Gaisser's Cosmic Rays and Particle Physics (ed. 2016).

[image]

I know $\theta$ and I have the vertical depths $X_{v}$. I want to solve for $X$ via a simple trigonometric relation. However, theta evolves as $\theta^*$ as you go up the atmosphere.

As Gaisser points out, the curvature of the Earth is the cause for the evolution of $\theta$. How would I go about correcting for this as a function of vertical depth?